# Subplot title in the same place as main title of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to add main title to plot and also minor titles to every single subplot. 
I cannot figure out how to do it properly. It happens that main title is located in the same place as a title of a subplot. 
How to move all subplots under main title? 
This is how I tried to do it:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.0, 5.0))
fig.suptitle('MAIN TITLE', horizontalalignment='left', fontsize=10)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.gca().set_title('SUBPLOT TITLE', fontsize=10)
```

Comment: Whe I run your code, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rJKl.png).  It looks ok to me. Can you explain exactly what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of a figure creation. It tries to arrange everything so that all features get their space.
And if you are still not convinced, you can control the space of the subplots with the rect kwarg, e.g.:

```
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1,. 95])
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html

Comment: I tried. It does not help. Perhaps I cannot use fig and plt separately on the same plot?

Comment: This should not be the problem. However,  after `fig = plt.figure()` I'd expect `fig.add_subplot(211)` if I remember correctly. But anyway, I'd recommend to use `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)`. Then you have everything you need in these variables right from the beginning.